# why does my loop skip conditions

Tags: assembly

this is my code :
placeStart is the first place of my player the cmp condition is executing one time instead of repeating it.

```
proc Shoot
    mov bx,[placeStart]
    mov dx,offset Game
    add bx,dx    
    ;; Moving to bx the position of the character
    mov cx,10
    check_shoot:
        cmp [byte ptr bx-NumCols],'+'  ;;checking if the shoot will override the plus 
        je exit 
        sub bx,NumCols
        mov [byte ptr bx],'*'
        cmp [byte ptr bx+NumCols],'*'
        je first_shoot
        jmp finish_loop
        first_shoot:
        mov [byte ptr bx+NumCols],' '
        finish_loop:
        call PrintGame
        loop check_shoot
```

Comment: What is `NumCols` exactly? An immediate constant defined with `equ`, or a variable (`db`/`dw`/`dd`)? You should post the complete, minimal code necessary to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do not even have a loop in your code. I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve, but you might want to make a `jmp` back to `check_shoot` or some such label. Only then you will you even have a loop in your code.

**Edit:** Adding a `loop check_shoot` after `call PrintGame`, you will see that the comparisons are independant of `cx` which is what is actually modified during a `loop`. Due to this, all your comparisons are the same each time the program loops, so you will get same results (though the `PrintGame` proc should've been called 10 times).

One suggestion is to use a debugger and to single step through your code to see if everything works as it should (i.e. whether you've actually coded things right).

Comment: after call PrintGame there is Loop check_shoot

Comment: That matters (to get a proper answer). I've edited the question based upon this (waiting for peer-review). I've also edited my answer to this effect.